# Fetch large amount of data through an API endpoint Python3.7

Tags: python, api

I have a dataframe with ~100 000 CUI ids, which I would like to use at an API endpoint to fetch some information.

Below is my code:

```
#call UMLS API to get CUI terms
umls_cui = open('umls_cui_names.txt', 'w')
missed_cui = open('not_found_cui.txt', 'w')

def get_cui(CUI):
        #api key
        API = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        #set the url
        url = 'https://uts-ws.nlm.nih.gov/rest/content/current/CUI/'
        url_cui = url + CUI
        #set the header
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        #set the parameters
        params = {'apiKey' : API}
    
        #send the request
        response = requests.get(url_cui, headers = headers, params = params)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            name = response.json()['result']['name']
            print (CUI, name)
            umls_cui.write("%s\t%s\n" % (CUI, name))
        else:
            print (response)
            print (response.json())
            print ('CUI not found')
            missed_cui.write("%s\n" % (CUI))
            pass


for i in df_cui['CUI']:
    print (i)
    get_cui(i)
    
umls_cui.close()
missed_cui.close()
```

After getting the data from ~12k CUI ids, I get response 502 error. Can anyone suggest a better way to fetch the complete data through the API.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the National Library of Medicine's API, and chose to ignore their ToS.
Apparently they return `502` status to non-compliant clients.

https://documentation.uts.nlm.nih.gov/terms-of-service.html

> API Terms of Service
>
> In order to avoid overloading our servers, NLM requires that users **send no more than 20 requests per second** per IP address. Requests that exceed this limit may not be serviced, and service will not be restored until the request rate falls beneath the limit. To limit the number of requests that you send to the APIs, NLM recommends caching results for a 24 hour period. This policy is in place to ensure that the service remains available and accessible to all users.

Reduce your request rate.

Use [time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) to measure the current rate.
Use [sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to reduce the rate.

---

When retrieving ~100 K CUI id search results,
use the `pageNumber` and `pageSize` parameters
to page through voluminous result records,
and follow [their advice](https://documentation.uts.nlm.nih.gov/rest/search/#paging-through-results) for detecting end-of-list.